# QGIS Misaligned Shape with Google Maps/OSM

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, coordinate-system, google-maps, alignment

I am using QGIS for a project.

I have started a new project from scratch within QGIS and have a set of Shape files that were given by the official government authorities.

The problem is that when I use Google Maps or OSM imagery I have a misalignment of about 200 meters, as you can see in the image provided.

[image]

I have set the SRC of the project to WGS84 EPSG:4326 so I can work in lat long.

The shape provided is in SRC:

```
ETRS89 / Portugal TM06 EPSG:3763.
```

I have also another shape, that is aligned with the previous in the SRC:

```
Lisboa_Hayford_Gauss_IGeoE EPSG:102164.
```

Both the shape files are aligned but not with Google Maps/OSM.

I already tried numerous SRC to fix this problem but it persists.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Looks like a projection issue.

Comment: Probably can't help you without a data sample.

Comment: Possibly check proj.4 strings in the CRS definitions to see what, if any transformations they're using (+wgs84 parameter). It would be great if they're using the Portuguese NTv2 files, but are likely using a 3 or 7 parameter transformation. Edit the question with the information?

Comment: The ETRS89 data should overlay relatively well with the WGS84 data,  unless the CRS definition is incorrect. The Lisboa Hayford definition needs a geographic/datum transformation for sure.

Comment: How do you change/use the geographic/datum tranformation?

Comment: @Robert datum transformations are expressed in QGIS using the `+towgs84` parameters different from zero. Try one of the `Portuguese` labelled CRS to see if it fits better than ETRS89.

Answer (score 3):

The Google Maps layer in QGIS via OpenLayers or QuickMapServices is never 100%, and the best way to use it is to set your map to EPSG 3857 (WGS 84 / Psuedo Mercator aka "Web Mercator")

Keep in mind that you shouldn't depend on the Google Maps layer for much more than a quick reference- you shouldn't be digitizing over this, as you'd be violating Google's terms of service, and I wouldn't be printing anything with Google as the basemap as you'll likely run into more alignment issues.